# Merging changes from multiple GIT repo's?

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to anything but the more basic features of GIT.  Here's the scenario.

I have multiple GIT repo's:

- Torque3D.git
- MyGame.git

Torque3D.git houses the sources for Torque3D.  Garage Games provides updates in the form of a source dump (no CSM access).  As Garage Games provides updates, Torque3D.git is updated with those changes.

MyGame.git is originally cloned from Torque3D.git and pulls those changes from Torque3D.git when appropriate.  In this scenario I'm always pulling ALL changes from Torque3D.git.  This works fine.

However as we make changes to the engine in MyGame.git, we on occasion want to push just a specific change back to Torque3D.git, but not all changes that have ever been made to MyGame.git.

How would we go about allowing for this kind of access?

Comment: It isn't an acronym, it is Git not GIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amber said, you probably want to make a separate branch with those changes.  Here's what I would do from a git repo with a MyGame branch, and a Torque3D branch set to track the T3D repo:

```
# should already have: git remote add t3d git://any/url/or/path/to/your/Torque3D.git
# should already have: git remote add origin git://any/url/or/path/to/your/MyGame.git
git checkout -b patchedT3D t3d/master
# use git log origin/master and find hashes of changes you want.  For each:
git cherry-pick c3df34262 # do this to add a rev's changes to Torque3d
# manually patch in whatever you want and commit if you have to
git push t3d +patchedT3D
# or push to whichever branch you want to have your changes with patchedT3D:<whatever>
git checkout -b withPatched origin/master
git merge --strategy=ours patchedT3D -m "mark your MyGame trunk as using the patched T3D changes so they don't get re-merged in later"
git push origin withPatched:master
```

That should give you an outline of one potential process to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate branch with only the changes you want to push back to Torque3D, and then pull from that branch into the Torque3D repo.